# The method '[]' was called on null, but works inApp

Tags: flutter, dart

my code is giving me an error.

"*The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: 
The relevant error-causing widget was
DetailPage*"

But in the app, the "red error screen" only appears for half a second, and the everything works as normal.

This is currenlly my code

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
    final String text;
  DetailPage ({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DetailPage createState() => _DetailPage();
}

class _DetailPage extends State<DetailPage> {
  Map mapResponse;
  Future fetchData() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse('');

    Response<String> response = await Dio().request(url.toString(),
        options: Options(
            headers: {}));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        mapResponse = json.decode(response.data);
      });
    }
  
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            bottom: false,
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 300),
                          Text(
                            mapResponse['item']['name'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontSize: 56,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
```

and this is how my json is

```
{
    "status": true,
    "item": {
        "name": "Name here",
    (moreJsonHere)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implies that it takes a short time for the data to be retrieved,

try this. It will pass a progress indicator for the short time while the data is empty

```
mapResponse !=null ? Text(
    mapResponse['item']['name'],
    style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
    fontSize: 56,
    color: Colors.blue,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    ):CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that `mapResponse` is null until the async function `fetchData` populates it. Since `fetchData` is async, the map is first null, then get populated, then setState is called and the warning goes away.

So what you want to do is check for map nullity:

```
Text((mapResponse == null) ? '' : mapResponse['item']['name'])
```

**For SDK>=2.11.0** you can use null-aware operator on map. So this would become:

```
Text(mapResponse?['item']?['name'] ?? '')
```